# Как реализовать поочерёдное копирование строк с помощью бота?

Tags: python

Как сделать так, чтобы бот в текстовом файле сначала копировал первую строку, вставлял её куда нужно, а затем вновь переходил к текстовому файлу и копировал уже вторую строку, и так по порядку?

Comment: `file.readline()`

Answer (score 0):

Массив строк из файла можно получить методом `.readlines()`. Вот решение циклом `for`:

```
with open('foobar.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines(): #идём по всем строкам
        #делаем что-то со строкой
```

А вот взятие строк *по номерам*

```
with open('foobar.txt', 'r') as f:
    foo = f.readlines()[0] #первая строка
    bar = f.readlines()[1] #вторая строка
    ...
```

Также можно читать строки с помощью метода `next()`:

```
with open('foobar.txt', 'r') as f:
    foo = next(fp) #первая строка
    bar = next(fp) #вторая строка
    ...
```

И ещё один вариант (с помощью `.readline()`):

```
with open('foobar.txt', 'r') as f:
    fp.seek(0) #идём в начало файла
    foo = f.readline() #первая строка
    bar = f.readline() #вторая строка
    ...
```

А ещё с помощью `.readline()` можно так:

```
with open('foobar.txt', 'r') as f:
    fp.seek(0) #идём в начало файла
    foo = f.readline() #первая строка
    bar = f.readline(10) #10я строка
    ...
```